# Identify valid getters and setters

Tags: java, setter, getter

I have a requirement like to scan a directory of java(POJO) files, go through each among them, and find out the corresponding variables defined in those POJO's, and to check whether it is having the correct getter and setter name. For Eg:- if `empName` is the variable name, then it should have getter as `getEmpName()` and not `getempName()`.

This is because our J2EE application which was build on long time back started failing     because of the use of invalid getters and setters, which is not recognizable with the front end technologies.

I have done a basic program in which this can be determined. My exact problem is like on what basis can i identify a variable in a line. In my logic i have written assuming the third word in a line which contains `private` keyword will be the variable name. just want to know whether this approach is right or do i need to try something different, as it seems the requirement is very generic.

Comment: Don't do it by scanning the source as text.  Use reflection.

Comment: I am not sure but apache-commons-beanutils may have something like this

Comment: It might be easier to use a code analysis tool such as checkstyle to do this.

Comment: Thanks guys, let me have a try with the above suggestions, meanwhile @ Qwerky, is it possible to set rules like to identify getters through checkstyle or sonar?

Comment: Yeap, either standard JEE or Custom one

Comment: Quick thought: A bean property (as expressed in the getter and setter names) does not always map directly to a member variable having the same name. And not all member variables should have getters and setters, even if access to those is limited; a bean, like any other class, may internal state that isn't exposed directly. The bean conventions aren't the complete answer.

Answer (score 3):

Trying to scan the source files yourself will be painful and involve a lot of edge cases etc.

For example the qualifiers on variables can be in any order, there can be multiple ones. Array brackets can be before or after the variable name, variable's may or may not be being initialized, etc. Some may be commented out or in an inner class.

Your best approach will be to use reflection and scan the objects using that.

Reflection is what allows running Java code to find out about itself. You can write a small program and add the code to scan as libraries for that program. The program can then scan through the classes in those Jars, and for each one use reflection to query the list of methods and variables within.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/

Comment: exactly u said, this is the big over head i am having. I havnt heard of reflection technique yet, can anybody suggest some good like to look into that?

Comment: I've added a bit of info on reflection for you.

Answer (score 1):

You are forgetting that variables can have more qualifiers than just the visibility qualifier:

```
private transient volatile int someVariable;
```

is valid syntax. It is a private variable which is not serialized and which is shared between threads.

It is also possible to have no visibility-qualifier, which results in a package-private variable (can be accessed by classes in the same package but not from classes in other packages).

```
int otherVariable;
```

What you can rely on is that the variable name itself is always followed by 0-n whitespaces and a `=` or a `;`. Unless it is an array, but exposing arrays with simple getters and setters is usually not a good idea.

Method names are always followed by 0-n whitespaces and a `(`.

Comment: thanks dude, i had a very similar approach what you have suggested gere, still need to go in more, to filter some more unwanted characters, now while testing i came across a method definition in the POJO, those things needs to be fintered i guess

Comment: @SureshkumarPanneerselvan Could you write an answer which explains which QA tools could be used for this and how to use them?

Comment: @Philipp Added answer.

Answer (score 1):

Most Of IDE's(Eclipse, Netbeans and IntelliJ IDEA) are having plugins for quality tools(Checkstyle, PMD and FindBug).

Externals tools like SONAR, FISHEYE are also you can use.

Kindly check this [link](http://www.eclipsezone.com/articles/pmd/) for PMD startup.